# How to configure multiple channel in fabric 1.0 using hyperledger-composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

We are having more than 3 peer, We would like to configure two different channel for two different group of peers. How to configure multiple channel into connection.json for the fabric 1.0?

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection profile defines the channel name to connect to, so you can create one connection profile (cpA) for channel A and another (cpB) for channel B. You can then deploy a business network archive (BNA) using cpA and using cpB using the `composer network deploy -p` command.

This will give you two channels with the same business network definition (same logic), each with their own ledger and world-state.

Comment: I thought, There will be way to configure multiple channel using single connection.json. Thank You Dan :)