# Multi-Channel support in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Currently a composer connection profile is specific to a channel i.e. only one channel can be specified in the connection profile. This makes it difficult to build an app that has to access multiple channels. For example, if a Buyer has many Suppliers and there is one Channel per Supplier, then a Buyer would require multiple connection profiles and multiple rest server instances, and any app that shows the data across all the suppliers would need to switch from one rest server to another (depending upon the supplier).

Is there any plan to support multiple channels in the connection profile, and pass the channel name dynamically?

Regards,
Naveen

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525752/how-to-configure-multiple-channel-in-fabric-1-0-using-hyperledger-composer

Comment: No that is not helpful....that interaction talks about how to create multiple channels using multiple connection profiles...as I mentioned above, such an approach makes it very difficult to create an app that spans multiple channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no plans at this time to support multiple channels in a single connection profile. Would be good if you could raise the requirement on github (https://github.com/hyperledger/composer) and describe your requirements in more detail so that it can be considered for inclusion in a future release.

Comment: Thanks David! I created issue #2103 - https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2103